apply Word character style to run_footnote in officer
I have 5 footnotes that I want to use in one place, and I want to make the footnotes print to the document with the "hidden" font feature. Instead of saying "1-2345" I want it to say "1-5". I have created a character style in the template document that makes things invisible, and I can apply it to a run_wordtext() object, but I cannot find the way to apply a character style to a run_footnote() object.
body_add(
 fpar(
  ftext("footnote text"), 
   run_footnote(x = footnotes_blocklist[15], prop = fp_text_refnote),
   ftext("-", prop = fp_text_refnote),
   run_footnote(x = footnotes_blocklist[16], prop = fp_text_refnote),
   run_footnote(x = footnotes_blocklist[17], prop = fp_text_refnote),
   run_footnote(x = footnotes_blocklist[18], prop = fp_text_refnote),
   run_footnote(x = footnotes_blocklist[19], prop = fp_text_refnote),
   run_footnote(x = footnotes_blocklist[20], prop = fp_text_refnote),
   run_footnote(x = footnotes_blocklist[21], prop = fp_text_refnote)))

I have looked into the fp_text() and fp_text_lite() functions, but they don't have an option for defining a character style. The only place I can see that argument being used is in run_wordtext(), which I can't incorporate into a run_footnote() object.
